# stream a window (frame) with subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, opencv, subprocess

I would like to stream a window (frame) with subprocess, sockets and cv2 using python.
I've been looking for a long time, but I didn't find anything.
The question is how can I catch the "images output" and then send it using sockets.

I guess I know how to deal with sockets and cv2. Still I need the "subsocket to cv2" part in the server script.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have some existing code which runs a subprocess that generates output. Show us that code so we can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve